# JSON : Unrecognized field "value" (<objectClass>), not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can someone help me to figure out what's need to be added?

JSON :

```
{"value":{"keyword":"better","correct":"","page":0,"size":10,"cost":51,"total":1107}}
```

Object class

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonRootName(value = "value")    
public class Response {

private int page;
private int size;
private int total;
private int cost;
private int result;

private String keyword;
private String correct;
```

Still it gets the "Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "value" (), not marked as ignorable"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your mapper config

```
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

If you use RestTemplate you will need to configure the underlying jackson mapper. You can do this by configuring your mapper and setting it in the converter. See code below.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);


MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(messageConverter);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

See here for more details: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-45

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By the way, I'm not using ObjectMapper, instead we use RestTemplate.